# Data table on click on dynamic controls

Tags: datatables

I have a jquery data table that I am populating from a drop down on change event. I have two check boxes in the data table and I am running an onclick on the check boxes. But on the first click the jquery does not fire only when I click it a second time does the jquery fire, also happens on switching pages.I added the .on() for the click, because I researched and saw that dynamic controls would work that way. Is there something I'm missing also to get this click function to work on first click? Below is some of my code.

[data table click on check box control no jquery click event on first click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYLl0.gif)

[data table click on check box control on second click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNnrq.gif)

```
      $('#my-table').on('click', function () {
    var i = -1;
    $("input[id*='secondary']:checkbox").on("click", function () {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            i = selectedIds.indexOf($(this).val());
            if (i === -1) {
                selectedIds.push($(this).val());
            }

            CheckedSecondary(this);
        }
        else {
            jQuery(this).closest("tr").css("background-color", "");

            if (selectedIds.length > 0) {
                i = selectedIds.indexOf($(this).val());
                if (i != -1) {
                    selectedIds.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
            if (!primaryChecked)
                $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).attr('disabled', false);
        }

    });

    $("#my-table").find("input[id*='primary']:checkbox").on("click", function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            primaryChecked = true;
            primaryID = this.value;

            CheckedPrimary(this);
        }
        else {
            primaryID = "";
            primaryChecked = false;
            $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).attr('disabled', false);

            $('input:checkbox[id^="primary"]').each(function () {

                if (!$(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked'))
                    $(this).attr('disabled', false);
            });
            jQuery(this).closest("tr").css("background-color", "");
        }

    });



});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attaching click handler inside another click handler which doesn't make sense.

Remove first click handler:

```
$('#my-table').on('click', function () {

});
```

Attach the click handler to the checkboxes as follows:

```
$('#my-table').on('click', "input[id*='secondary']:checkbox", function () {

});
```

and

```
$('#my-table').on('click', "input[id*='primary']:checkbox", function () {

});
```

Comment: Thank you, for such a simple fix.